# InternalServerError Object reference not set to an instance of an object when creating an open extension using Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I received "InternalServerError", "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when creating an open extension for a group.

I tried to create an open extension for a group:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[group id]/extensions
{
  "@odata.type" : "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
  "extensionName": "com.test.1235",
  "watermarks": "abc",
  "id": "com.test.1235"
}

Headers:
Authorization: bearer [access token]
Content-Type: application/json
```

This is the response I received:

```
500 Internal Server Error
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "56d5fd05-cf69-4a91-85b6-dcfce7894e13",
            "date": "2019-06-17T10:52:44"
        }
    }
}

Headers:
request-id: 56d5fd05-cf69-4a91-85b6-dcfce7894e13
client-request-id: 56d5fd05-cf69-4a91-85b6-dcfce7894e13
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Southeast Asia","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_5","ADSiteName":"SEA"}}
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 10:52:44 GMT
```

This did not just happen for groups. Creating an extension for a user also returned the same error. Given the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." message I assume there is a bug somewhere in the backend. Otherwise please let me know how to fix the request to avoid this error.

Comment: Can you try this without the `id` property (i.e.` "test-id": "com.test.1235"``)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're rolling back to the previous Graph deployment while we investigate and root cause the issue.  The issue should be mitigated shortly and then API requests to create open extensions should be working again. Thank you for reporting this!